# Can not get weather values from the API with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I try to get the weather values from the weather API and i can not take the city name and the other properties. When i try to push them in the array items can not project it to HTML page

See the code below:

```
var url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=london,gb,&key=f0e406af6ebf4937862f9f50ae78125b";

function getWeather(){
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    var weather = {
      cityName:val.city_name,
      longtitude:val.lon,
      timezone:val.timezone,
      latitude:val.lat,
      countryState:val._state
    }


    items.push("<li>"+weather+"</li>");
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
}
```

Comment: var weather is a JavaScript object. It will not create a valid HTML element when surrounded by li tags.

Comment: You need to access the objects by their properties, not by attempting to concatenate them to a string or `join()` them like an array. You also don't need a loop as there is only one set of `city_name`, `lon`, `lat` etc returned in the response. Which values are you trying to show in the UI?

Comment: Your API response contains weather forecast for a single location ('London', as your url parameter states) and multiple days. That array is encompassed within `data` property of response object (which you have named `data` as well, so you need to traverse `data.data`). Within array items there's no information about city and state it is in the top level properties of your object.

Comment: I am trying to show city name, timezone and country state and get the weather due to lon and lat

Comment: @GeoD Please have a look at the updated answer. Thats what you want.

Comment: @GeoD dont forget to up-vote and accept the as "the" answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can access those properties like in the demo.

Here is working **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/acghx45z/19/

```js
var url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=london,gb,&key=f0e406af6ebf4937862f9f50ae78125b";

function getWeather(){
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  let newData = {}
    $.each(data, function( key, val ) {
      if (key != 'data') {
        newData[key] = data[key]
      } 
    });
    $.each(newData, function( key, val ) {
      items.push("<li>"+key+" : "+val+"</li>");
    });
    
  $( "<ul/>", {"class": "my-new-list",html: items}).appendTo( "body" );
 });
}

getWeather()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version:

```js
var url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=london,gb,&key=f0e406af6ebf4937862f9f50ae78125b";

function getWeather(){
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
  var items = [];

  items.push("<li>"+data.city_name+"</li>");
  items.push("<li>"+data.lon+"</li>");
  items.push("<li>"+data.timezone+"</li>");
  items.push("<li>"+data.lat+"</li>");
  items.push("<li>"+data.state_code+"</li>");


  $( "<ul>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
}

getWeather();
```

You don't need a loop. In fact, from what you're trying to do, a loop makes no sense if all you're trying to get are these specific values.

In your code, you loop over every key in the data object and create a new object with every iteration that gets then pushed to your items array. You are also trying to access undefined values.

<strike>The answer from above isn't correct since it goes through every key in the object which itself can be an object and results in broken output like [object].</strike>

Have a look at the documentation over at mozilla: [Javascript - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)